# Yii2 получение данных из таблицы со связями

Tags: yii2

Имеется 2 таблицы (users и contacts) связанные между собой. 
Users (id, ...)- информация о пользователе
Contacts (id, my_id, contact_id) - кто кого добавил к себе в контакты

В модели users прописано:

```
public function getContact()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Contacts::className(), ['contact_id' => 'id']);
}
```

В модели Contacts прописано:

```
 public function getUser()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'contact_id']);
}
```

В SiteController запрашиваем мои контакты:

```
$qwe = Contacts::findOne(['my_id' => 1]);
$contacts = $qwe->getUser()->all();
```

код отрабатывает и возвращает 1 первый мой контакт, но необходимо получить все мои контакты, по логике пишу так:

```
$qwe = Contacts::findAll(['my_id' => 1]);
$contacts = $qwe->getUser()->all();
```

но тут вылетает ошибка:
Call to a member function getUser() on array

Что не так? Как получить все мои контакты?

Answer (score 1):

В Yii2 метод findAll возвращает массив объектов типа ActiveRecord, как написано в [документации](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#findAll()-detail)

> An array of ActiveRecord instances, or an empty array if nothing matches.

Массив можно обработать классическим перебором `

```
foreach($qwe as $item) { 
    $linkedData = $item->getUser()->all(); 
    // Потом делаете то, что вам надо 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас в связи getUser должно быть hasMany судя по всему.

Comment: Пробовал и так, результат тот же: ошибка

Comment: Тогда вам по логике нужно запрашивать контакты от модели юзера, а не от модели(ей) контактов.
В классе юзера добавить связь
`return $this->hasMany(User::className(), ['id' => 'contact_id'])->viaTable('contacts', ['my_id' => 'id']);`